# Xamarin Tabbed Pages MVVM Passing Data Between Pages

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a TabbedPage called 'TabContainerPage' that is a container for two ContentPage.

```
<TabbedPage.Children>
        <me:TabbedPage1View Title="Tabbed Page 1" BindingContext="{Binding tabbedPage1ViewModel}" WidthRequest="400"/>
        <me:TabbedPage2View Title="Tabbed Page 2"/>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

In the TabContaierPageViewModel I have a property to the the TabbedPage1ViewModel called 'tabbedPage1ViewModel'

```
public TabbedPage1ViewModel tabbedPage1ViewModel  { get; set; }

public TabContainerPageViewModel()
{
      tabbedPage1ViewModel = new TabbedPage1ViewModel ();
}
```

In the TabPage1ViewModel I have a List of Items

```
private List<Items> _items;

public List<Items> items
{
            get
            {
                return _items;
            }
            set
            {
                _items = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
}
```

From the TabPage1View I navigate to another page called 'AddItemView.'

As the name implies, I add a new Item with a simple Name and Description on the AddItemView page.

When I click the back button to go back to TabPage1View I want to update the list of items to be displayed on that page.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: use an ObservableCollection instead of a List, and/or share the same VM between the two pages, or use MessagingCenter, or just pass an object reference to the new item

Comment: What's the advantage of using Observable Collection over a List?

Comment: an ObservableCollections raises a CollectionChanged event when an item is added/removed, so that your UI can update itself automatically

Comment: I'm populating the Lists from an Sqlite database table. So it would be advantageous for me to switch from Lists to ObservableCollections? How can I pass a reference of TabePage1ViewModel to the AddItemView? I'm setting the binding context in the TabPageContainer Xaml: `<me:TabbedPage1View Title="Tabbed Page 1" BindingContext="{Binding tabbedPage1ViewModel}"/>`

Comment: just pass it in the constructor for Page2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, change List to ObservableCollection.

ObservableCollection implements by itself the OnPropertyChanged, what means that the interface will update when the collection updates.

But you still need to reload your model on TabPage1View (after adding the item and comming back from AddItemView).

You have two options:

First and best, implement a MessagingCenter. Fire a message befor close AddItemView, intercept the message in TabPage1View, update the Observable and your screen will update as well.

Second, do the same at TabPage1View.PageAppearing.

One last hint: sometimes you need to remove one by one the items in the collections, and the add the new items to fire the UI refresh.

If you replace the old observabel witha new one, the UI may not refresh.

Comment: Do I subscribe to the message from the TabPage1ViewModel? I don't understand how to access the instance of the tabbed page's view model because it's being set in the Xaml file of the TabbedPageContainer like so `<me:TabbedPage1View Title="Tabbed Page 1" BindingContext="{Binding tabbedPage1ViewModel}"/>`

Comment: Yes, subscribe to the message in tabbedPage1ViewModel.
You dont need to access the specific instance of your view model.

In your tabbedPage1ViewModel subscribe the message:

```MessagingCenter.Subscribe<AddItemView, string>(this, "ItemAdded", (sender, arg) =>
{
  remove the itens from collection;
  add new itens to the collection;
}```

In the AddItemView, after add ou delete one item, fire the message:
```MessagingCenter.Send<AddItemView, string>(this, "ItemAdded", ItemId);```